# Excel: keep formula even if I delete row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Suppose I have the following formula

```
=Sheet1!$A$1
```

I would like to keep it also If I delete Row 1. So that if I have in Sheet1:

A1: 1

A2: 2

So that the formula gives me 1 as long as I have first and second row. If now I remove the first row I would like the formula to give back 2 instead of #REF!

How can I keep the formula valid even upon row removal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
=index(sheet1!a:a, 1)
```

By hardcoding the row number, you will not receive the `#ref!` error when A1 is deleted; it simply uses the new A1.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the indirect formula:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!A1")
```

Comment: Of course, INDIRECT is considered a volatile function and will recalculate whenever anything in any open workbook changes.

Comment: Agreed. But it shouldn't make a difference it is used only a few times.

Comment: Which is the difference between this one and INDEX?

Comment: @Simons123 The two formulas are used for very different purposes.